# No output when running C++ applications via Eclipse CDT IDE

Tags: c++, mingw, eclipse-cdt, execution, eclipse-indigo

Eclipse can build my applications for me so far, and I can execute them directly (via Windows 7 Explorer), but I get no results when I use the run command via the CDT perspective. The console tab only tells me that the application terminated, even with a console app with input (cin >> and so forth). Win32 apps don't execute either. Once again I can execute them directly via the debug folder, so this must be an IDE issue. Is this normal? Or are there settings I could change to make it work?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: To see whether your application really isn't running or it's just a display problem, have your program create a file in a known location and check whether it was created.

Comment: The file wasn't created when I ran it via the IDE (ctrl-F11 on my machine), but it was created when I ran it directly in the debug folder. So the IDE can't even execute it for some reason.

Comment: One more thought: what's the current directory when the application runs?  Did you use an absolute or relative path name for the created file?  Could the file have been created in some unexpected location?  If you used an absolute path name and it still didn't create it, then something else is going on.  Maybe a permissions problem (check the ownership of the executable).

Comment: Well once again, when I execute it directly from windows explorer it works correctly, and the test file is created in the same directory as my application (C:\Program Files\eclipse\workspace\FileTest\Debug). The file is specified as a relative path in my program (just "example.txt"). I'm currently running eclipse as administrator as well. Maybe I should move eclipse out of program files, since maybe its a problem with spaces in the file location. I'll try that.

Comment: First, please try specifying an absolute path name for the created file, such as `"C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\workspace\\FileTest\\Debug\\example.txt"`.  If that works, try writing the name of the current directory to that file (I'm not sure how to get that in Windows).  I'm trying to figure out whether your program is actually running from the IDE, but with a working directory different from what you're expecting.  Maybe `example.txt` is being created somewhere else, and you're not seeing it.

Comment: Yes! It Works now, it was because there was a space in "Program Files". Probably a MinGW issue. Thanks Keith!

Comment: If that's the solution, you should add it as an answer.  (I would, but you're the one who solved it; I didn't think of the space in "Program Files" being an issue).

Comment: Yeah, I think it's written in the MinGW website somewhere that it has a problem with spaces for some reason. Not quite sure why though. And I can't answer my question yet because the 8 hour time limit isn't over, apparently thats what new people like me have to get through since I don't have 100 reputation yet. So I'll answer it in about 5 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! It's because my workspace was in the "Program Files" directory, which has a space in it. Probably a MinGW issue.

Thanks to Keith Thompson for the help though!

Comment: For what's worth, you can always use the debugger perspective and ran it there. Then you'll see the output as well, even if your workspace directory has a space in it ;)